# Adding duplicates in an ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

I am stuck on how to find duplicate entries in an ArrayList and then manipulate them.  I am implementing a polynomial class and I want to add monomials of the same order to create a new polynomial.  Monomials have a degree and a coefficient.  I want to cycle through a collection of monomials and find the monomials that have the same power and add the coefficients.  The sum of all these like powered monomials will be the polynomial.

Comment: What's the problem? If you want to sort & find them by their power, you could use a map-based collection keyed on their power.

Comment: Where does the ArrayList fit in here?

Comment: Can you show the code with the problem? Java ArrayList list acceps duplicates, what exactly collection do you use?

Comment: could you explain a little more what you are storing and how in the array list?

Comment: The ArrayList contains objects of type Monomial the entirety of which represents a Polynomial?

Comment: I am very sorry.  I posted the question from my phone.  I am on the bus right now and will post my src as soon as I get home.  I edited my question about to try and be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList (or any List) accepts duplicates.

However, since you want to group Monomials by their power, you might consider using a `Map<Integer,Foo>` where the key is the power.  Foo has a lot of options.  Foo could be an `ArrayList<Monomial>`, an `ArrayList<Double>`, holding only the coefficiants, that you add later.  This requires some code writing on your part or else using a 3rd partly library for a MultiMap.

Or, Foo could be a Double which represents the summed coefficient, in which case you need to write an add(Monomial) method which updates the Double everytime.

If the possible range of powers is small and known, you could use a simple array too.

Comment: I do have an add(monomial) method.  I really like your map suggestion.  Say I used a HashMap.  How can I update foo when two monomials hash to the same location?

Comment: Note that it's only the power, not the complete Monomial, that has to map to the same location.  At that point, if you are using the ArrayList, make sure the ArrayList exists, (creating if needed), thent add the Monomial (or the coefficient) to the ArrayList.  You'll then need some form of "addItAllUp()" method at the end.

Comment: If you are using the Double version, every add will create a new Double, with the sum of the old one (or 0 if there was none) and the new coefficient.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution, you can add two polynomials of the same degree. Watch for bugs.

```
public class Polynome {


    private double[] coefficients;
    private int degre;



    public Polynome(int degre) {

        if (degre < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Degree");
        }

        this.degre = degre;
        coefficients = new double[degre + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < degre; i++)
            coefficients[i] = 0;

        coefficients[degre] = 1;
    }


    public void setCoefficient(int degre, double coefficient) {
        if (degre < 0 || degre > this.degre) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Degree");
        }

        if (coefficient == 0 && degre == this.degre && this.degre != 0) {
            System.out.println("Null Degree");
        }

        coefficients[degre] = coefficient;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the coeff giving the degree of the element
     */
    public double getCoefficient(int degre) {
        if (degre < 0 || degre > this.degre) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (degre == this.degre && this.degre != 0) {
            return coefficients[this.getDegre()];
        }

        return this.coefficients[degre];
    }



    public String ToString() {

        if (degre == 0)
            return "" + this.coefficients[0];

        String result = "" + this.coefficients[degre]+" x^" + degre;
        for (int i = degre-1  ; i > 0 ; i--){
            if (this.coefficients[i] < 0) {
                result += "-" + Math.abs(this.coefficients[i]) + " x^" + i;
            }
            else {
                if (this.coefficients[i] > 0){
                    result += " + " + this.coefficients[i] + " x^" + i;
                }
            }
        }

        if (this.coefficients[0]!= 0) result += " + " + this.coefficients[0]  ;
        return result;
    }



    /*
     * Returns the degree of the current poly
     */
    public int getDegre() {
        return degre;
    }


    /*
     * Adds two Polys with the same degrees
     */
    public Polynome add(Polynome p) {
        Polynome result = new Polynome(p.getDegre());
        int deg = result.getDegre();


        for(int i = deg  ; i >0 ; i--) {
            result.coefficients[i] = this.getCoefficient(i) + p.getCoefficient(i);
        }

        return result;
    }






    public static void main(String...args) {
        Polynome p = new Polynome(2);
        p.setCoefficient(2, 7);

        Polynome p1 = new Polynome(2);
        p1.setCoefficient(2, 2);

        System.out.println(p.ToString() + "\n" + p1.ToString() + "\n\n" + (p.add(p1)).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: The code must be automatically formatted, toString must be written with a lowercase t, input validation must use exceptions instead of System.out, each condition in getCoefficient must be relevant, degree must be spelled correctly.